# Finding maximum of 3 numbers using nested if/else statements

Tags: c#, nested

So I'm in college and I'm writing a program using C# which is ALMOST done except for this button.  I don't want the answer because I'll never learn that way, but I'm writing a program using Heron's method where the user has to input 3 numbers to determine if these numbers can be used as sides of a triangle.  The one button I am confused with is the Finding the Maximum button which wants the program to show which number entered is the highest.  The professor wants this code to be written using nested if/else statements.  I have searched online and the book for the course is terrible.  Could someone help me with a possible web site to help or maybe an example? That would be GREATLY appreciated.

Comment: You need to determine which of three numbers is the largest using 'if' statements?

Comment: • Use a nested If / Else statement to find the biggest input number. Assume that the numbers are not equal.  Display the maximum in the provided Label. <~ those are the exact directions. It's not even in my book.

Comment: Bad professor, he needs to join the modern world and use linq...

Comment: What do you have so far?  What are you stuck on?

Comment: Even if you don't use LINQ, you still shouldn't have nested if/else statements.  That's just bad code.  You should loop through each item in a collection (put the items in a collection if they're not in one) and compare each one to a local variable with the current "max".  Only you know if your professor will be happy or upset if you try that on your work though.  I've known some that would do either.

Comment: @user1695473: what construct are you using to store the values entered currently?

Comment: Using LINQ to solve this seems to be the sledgehammer/nut solution. Two Math.Max() calls will achieve this.

Comment: Not all languages will have LINQ. And using a COLLECTION to compare for max value between 3 variables is also overkill.

While two Math.Max() calls would be most efficent, the requirements are to use nested if/else statements. We can infer the lesson is to learn how to use if/else statements and not how to use LINQ, Collections, or efficently comparing numbers for max value.

Comment: @StarPilot I agree. I was responding to the comments that implied that LINQ was the 'correct' method of achieving the result.

Comment: Check this > [C# program to find the largest of five number using else if](http://www.msccomputerscience.com/2014/04/c-program-to-find-biggest-number-of.html)

Comment: All code of if else would be same whether I write it in C or C#. [C program to find maximum between three numbers using nested if](http://codeforwin.blogspot.in/2015/05/c-program-to-find-maximum.html)

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps you could write it using a two-level nested Math.Max(v1, v2) request. Then translate that into the necessary If/else clauses. Maybe you can get bonus points if you download [ILSpy](http://ilspy.net/) and inspect System.Math.Max to see what .Net uses under the covers.

Answer (score 0):

I remember problems like these from university. Break the solution down so that you're comparing two of the numbers at a time. Once you have the maximum from the first pair, compare that to the third. Something like:

```
int a, b, c;

if (a > b)
{
    if (a > c)
        return a;
    else
        return c;
}
else
{
    /* similar for b/c pair */
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need I can write the entire program. But to get max outta three numbers here is the pseudo code.

```
`var n1 = GetInputFromUser` >> General methods in C# console is Console.Readline() and in case of forms its good ole TextBoxes.
var n2 = GetInputFromUser
var n3 = GetInputFromUser

var result

if (n1 > n2)
        {
            result = n1;

            if (n1 > n3)
                result = n1;
            else
                result = n3;
        }
        else
        {
            result = n2;
            if(n2 > n3)
                result = n2;
            else
                result = n3;
        }
```

Hope this helps

Comment: this is practically the format i used! thank you so much, it now works.

Answer (score -2):

If you have to use nested if statements, I would look into using a temp variable.  something like:

```
var temp
var input1
var input2
var input3

if input1> input2 then
     temp = input1
else
    temp = input2
```

Something similar to this should be sufficient. I didn't go into the whole thing as only an example was asked for, and OP specifically said they didn't want the answer.

Comment: Not quite sufficient as you didn't take into account input3, but we'll leave that as exercise to the OP since he didn't want the answer here.

Comment: if you're trying to show an example of nested 'if' statements, nest some 'if' statements

Comment: @JimWooley: Right.  I didn't want to go too much more into it, since he didn't want the answer, only an example.  Figured it was sufficient to garner the rest.

Comment: *she ;) i figured it out. thanks all for your different suggestions!

Comment: @MStodd: Wasn't really showing an example of a nested if statement, only the use of a temp variable for comparison.