# C# - Finding maximum of 3 numbers using if / else statements

Tags: c#

I'm completely new to C# - just trying out some simple stuff.
I want to find the maximum of three numbers, using if/else statements. I tried writing this method:

```
public int Maximum(int num1, int num2, int num3)
    {
        if (num2 < num1 > num3)
        {
            return num1;
        }

        else if (num1 < num2 > num3)
        {
            return num2;
        }

        else if (num1 < num3 > num2)
        {
            return num3;
        }
    }
```

but I've gotten a bit confused.

Q1 - By saying "int Maximum", do I still need to declare each parameter as being an int (or the same the other way round)? Or does everything need its data type declared?

Q2 - Keeps telling me that "Operator '>' cannot be applied to operands of type bool and int"? I'm confused as to what I should do here. Have I done something wrong or is there an alternative?

Thanks for any help.

Comment: What's your reference material? How are you studying?

Comment: Not really anything in particular yet. Just been searching around for the basics

Comment: Q1 if I understand right, yes you need to declare each parameter type. When you declare int Maximum, you declare witch type will function return, then you must to declare types for variables witch you will pass to function

Comment: If you want to be serious, study seriously. What you're doing right now is like trying to write a Chinese book by looking at a few lines and sketches (assuming you don't know Chinese...)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12572044/finding-maximum-of-3-numbers-using-nested-if-else-statements

Comment: I do intend to study "seriously", and I will. As I said, I'm searching. Give it less than half an hour and I'll probably be started on something properly.

Comment: It looks to me as if you whatever guide you are using is either not meant for beginners or you have skipped several sections. For instance, Maximum is a function. Putting int before its name in the declaration means it is returning data of type int. So maybe change to a more accessible guide, or just don't get ahead of yourself.

Comment: I've been doing python for a bit, so I'm not a complete beginner at programming in general. Just to C#

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Regarding Q1

C# is a [strongly typed](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strong_and_weak_typing) language. This means that you must explicitly tell the compiler the types of your parameters, variables, members, and even your methods return value.

This is similar to other strongly typed languages, such as Java or C++.

***P.S.:*** Newest C# keywords (such as `var` or `dynamic`) try to move C# from a strongly typed environment to an *hybrid* one.

## Regarding Q2

`num < num2 > num3` is not a valid condition expression.

`num < num2` yields a `bool`, so the following expression `num < num2 > num3` would be equivalent to `bool > num3`, which is invalid, since you can't compare a bool and an int like this.

What you're looking for is the [Conditional AND (&&)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2a723cdk.aspx) operator:

```
if (num < num2 && num2 > num3)
{
    return num2;
}
```

Alternatively, you can also use nested `if` statements to achieve the same behaviour:

```
if (num < num2)
{
    if (num2 > num3)
    {
        return num2;
    }
}
```

## Regarding your code

The code you have provided has another problem.

What would happen if none of the three conditions are met? What would the method return?

Of course, you know that it's not possible for the three conditions to never be met, *but the compiler doesn't know this*.

You have to either return a dummy value, or remove your last `else if`:

```
public int Maximum(int num1, int num2, int num3)
{
    if (num2 < num1 && num1 > num3)
    {
        return num1;
    }

    else if (num1 < num2 && num2 > num3)
    {
        return num2;
    }

    // If we reached this point, we know that num3 is the biggest of them all
    else
    {
        return num3;
    }
}
```

Comment: What if num1 = num2 and num2 > num 3 e.g. num1=2, num2,=2, num3=1. Your logic would return num3.

Answer (score 2):

The statement inside the brackets () must result in true or false. The way it is written will not work as you are not comparing two values. Instead you should write:

```
public int Maximum(int num1, int num2, int num3)
{
    if ((num2 < num1) && (num1 > num3))
    {
        return num1;
    }

    else if ((num1 < num2) && (num2 > num3))
    {
        return num2;
    }

    else
    {
        return num3;
    }
}
```

Comment: You can't write `return null` unless you declare the method signature as `public int? Maximum(...)`. Usually you would throw some Invalid*-Exception.

Comment: I made a mistake there, since they are else if statements. They will never get to the return null. Although it says that it will return an int I believe it is possible to return a null value. The variable just needs to be nullable.

Comment: I have edited accordingly. SharpShade, you were correct.

Answer (score 2):

I think the basic answer would be like this for you(a new learner):

```
 int num1 = 1, num2 = 2, num3 = 3;
 int max;
 if (num1 >= num2)
 {
    if (num3 >= num1)
    {
       max = num3;
    }
    else
    {
       max = num1;
    }
 }
 else
 {
    if (num3 >= num2)
    {
       max = num3;
    }
    else
    {
       max = num2;
    }
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

A1: yes, you have to declare the types of all parameters. The parameter type is nothing to do with your return type.

A2: you expect a bool value from your if statement but (n2 < n1 > n3) means (n2 < n1) > n3 -> bool > int. You cannot compare a boolean value with an integer.

If you really want to do it in a if else way,

```
if(num1 > num2)
{
    if(num1 > num3 )
        return num1;
    else 
        return num3;
}
else
{
    if(num2 > num3)
        return num2;
    else
        return num3;
}
```